# Firestore dynamic link crash on ios

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

The code works fine on android devices but it does not work on ios devices.

my code:

```
String userId = uid;
final DynamicLinkParameters dynamicLinkParameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
    uriPrefix: 'https://mywebsite.com/user/',
    link: Uri.parse(
      'https://mywebsite.com/link/?username=$userId',
    ),
  );

  final ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink = await dynamicLink.buildShortLink(
    dynamicLinkParameters,
    shortLinkType: ShortDynamicLinkType.short,
  );
```

error message:

```
flutter: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
2022-07-29 22:30:23.235625+0300 Runner[51971:280704] flutter: 
#0 new LinkedHashMap.from.<anonymous closure> (dart:collection/linked_hash_map.dart:187:26)
#1 _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:614:13)
#2 new LinkedHashMap.from (dart:collection/linked_hash_map.dart:186:11)
#3 platformExceptionToFirebaseException  (package:firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils /exception.dart:32:9)
#4 convertPlatformException  (package:firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:5)
#5 MethodChannelFirebaseDynamicLinks.buildShortLink (package:firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_dynamic_links.dart:196:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled it by changing

from

```
uriPrefix: 'https://mywebsite.com/user/',
```

to

```
uriPrefix: 'https://mywebsite.com/user',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
String userId = uid;
```

to

```
int userId = uid;
```

Comment: The problem is not about userId. Already uid is a string.